# find the max no of people allowed at the base of human tower using recursion

Tags: python, recursion

Consider that the human tower is to be performed on a stage and the stage has a maximum weight limit.

Write a python program to find the maximum number of people at the base level such that the total weight of tower does not exceed the maximum weight limit of the stage.

Assume that:
1. Each person weighs 50 kg 
2. There will always be odd number of men at the base level of the human tower.

i couldnt understand how to solve it

Comment: Are u failing the problem-solving or python-part?

Comment: i could understand how to use recursion in the problem

Comment: This sounds like an assignment. The problem statment is not clear in my opinion. What are the rules for a tower? Is it a pyramid? Are you taking a CS class in Barcelona btw? (catalans love to build human towers)

Comment: nope it is an assignment from infytq certification

Answer (score 2):

This looks more like a math problem than a programming issue.  Reducing the problem to its simplest mathematical representation will usually provide the most efficient programming solution.

Assuming the "tower" is like a pyramid, i.e. there is one fewer man on each higher level.

Here's what we can infer:

- The `base` is an odd number which can be represented as `2*n+1`
- The total number of people in the pyramid `P` can be calculated by `base*(base+1)/2`
- The weight of all the people in the pyramid is `P*50` which cannot exceed a given value `M` (which I guess will be an input from the user)
- In the best case scenario the weight will be equal to the maximum: `50*base*(base+1)/2 = M`
- Now, a little algebra...
- M = 50*base*(base+1)/2
- M = 50*(2*n+1)*(2*n+2)/2       *(odd base = 2*n+1)*
- M = 25*(4*n^2 + 6*n + 2)
- M = 100*n^2 + 150*n + 50       *(lo and behold a quadratic equation)*
- 0 = 2*n^2 + 3*n + 1 - M/50
- n = (-3 + √(9-4*2*(1-M/50))/4
- n = √(9 - 8 + 4*M/25)/4 - 3/4
- n = √(4*M/25+1)/4 - 3/4
- base = 2*n+1

So your program could be as simple as:

```
from math import sqrt
M    = int(input("Maximum weight on stage (Kg): "))
n    = sqrt(4*M/25+1)/4 - 3/4     
base = 2*int(n)+1                    # int(n) to ignore fractions of people
print("Base of the pyramid: ",base,"men")
```

You can make it prove itself too:

```
totalWeight = 50*base*(base+1)/2
print("Pyramid Weight: ",totalWeight,"Kg")
overWeight = 50*(base+2)*(base+3)/2
print("Weight if base were",base+2,"men: ",overWeight,"Kg")
```

...

```
Maximum weight on stage (Kg): 3000
Base of the pyramid:  9 men
Pyramid Weight:  2250.0 Kg
Weight if base were 11 men:  3300.0 Kg
```

...

```
Maximum weight on stage (Kg): 3299
Base of the pyramid:  9 men
Pyramid Weight:  2250.0 Kg
Weight if base were 11 men:  3300.0 Kg
```

...

```
Maximum weight on stage (Kg): 3300
Base of the pyramid:  11 men
Pyramid Weight:  3300.0 Kg
Weight if base were 13 men:  4550.0 Kg
```

If you're not allowed a mathematical solution, you can use an iterative approach:

```
base = next(b-2 for b in range(3,M,2) if 50*b*(b+1)/2 > M)
```

*Compute the total weight for every odd base until you go over the maximum, then use the previous odd base.  Presumably, if there are not at least 3 people, you don't even have a pyramid, so you can start this process at 3*

If you need it to be a procedural algorithm, this will translate to:

```
base       = 1     # preceding base
nextweight = 300   # weight for base = 3
while nextweight <= M:
    base       += 2                          # advance base (odd)
    nextweight += 50*(base+1) + 50*(base+2)  # next total weight
```

if you need a recursive solution, you could have a function call itself until if reaches apoint where the next base will exceed the maximum weight:

```
def oddBase(M,base=1,total=50):
    total += 50*(base+1)  # add one level at the bottom, next even base
    total += 50*(base+2)  # add one level at the bottom, next odd base
    if total > M : return base
    return oddBase(M,base+2,total)

oddBase(3300)  # 11
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an optimization problem; each layer on a human pyramid has one less person than the one below it; the total of people on the human pyramid is given by this formula:

n + (n - 1) + (n - 2) + ... + 2 + 1

Where `n` is the number of people on the base of the pyramid.

The formula above can be simplified by seeing it as a triangle with base `n` and height `n-1`:

n * (n - 1) / 2

The total weight is can be given by multiplying this by 50:

w = 50 * n * (n - 1) / 2

Also, n must be odd, that is, its modulo by 2 should be 1:

n % 2 = 1

So, you have an optimization problem where you want to:

- Maximize `n`;
- `50 * n * (n - 1) / 2 < m`;
- `n % 2 = 1`.

Given `n` is a free variable representing the width of the base and `m` is the maximum weight.

Comment: In this case, n also has to be odd

Answer (score 0):

In a human tower,the number of people in each level starts decreasing by 1 when we progress from bottom to the top.

If 5 people are standing at the base,4 people will be standing on the people in the base and so on until one person stands on the very top.
You can try something like this,

```
i=1
while(1):
    if(sum(list(range(1,i+1)))*50 > weight_threshold):
        print(i-1)
        break
    i+=1
```

If you need only odd numbers at the base.then use i+=2 instead of i+=1

Comment: i need the number of people at base not the total number of people

Comment: that's what it prints

Answer (score 0):

def human_pyramid(no_of_people):

```
if(no_of_people==1):
    return 1*(50)
else:
    return no_of_people*(50)+human_pyramid(no_of_people-2)
```

def find_maximum_people(max_weight):

```
no_of_people=0
person_weight = 50
number = max_weight / person_weight
i=1
while(1):
    if(sum(list(range(1,i+1,2)))*50 > max_weight):
        break
    i+=2
    print(i)
i = i-2
return i
```

max_people=find_maximum_people(1050)

print(max_people)

Ps : I have used rahul code and modified it to get better results